# Ansible: Ping from remote host

Tags: ansible

I have host A managed with Ansible. I have host B (Host B is not available in inventory) where I am executing few  commands with "delegate_to". Host C is my ansible controller. I am trying to ping a ipaddress from host B with "delegate_to". This ipaddress is somewhere on host D (Host D is not available in inventory), however I am not aware how to use ping module to to achieve this. So I am using command module.

```
- name: Ping net1
  command: 'ping -c 4 10.17.12.2'
  delegate_to: 10.17.10.85
```

How can I achieve same functionality in better way?

Answer (score 1):

An Ansible "ping" is actually checking for ssh, and as far as I know there isn't an Ansible module made to check for network connectivity between hosts (could maybe use wait_for?) So this might be the best way, although I would add a `changed_when: false` to properly reflect the fact that this command will never change anything:

```
- name: Ping net1
  command: 'ping -c 4 10.17.12.2'
  delegate_to: 10.17.10.85
  changed_when: false
```

Answer (score 0):

`wait_for` seems to be the standard way of doing it.

e.g. (assuming port 22 will be open)

```
wait_for:
  host: 10.17.12.2
  port: 22
  delay: 5
  state: started
  timeout: 10
  delegate_to: 10.17.10.85
```